# How To Generate A Unique ID On A Field In Oracle Apex When Tab/Enter Button Is Pressed?

Tags: oracle, forms, oracle-apex

I am trying to generate a ***unique ID*** on `Oracle Apex Forms` field while **`Enter/Tab`** button is pressed like we do in `Oracle Forms` using the **`Key-Next-Item`** And **`Post-Change`** *triggers* on a field.

Answer (score 2):

This is not Forms, this is Apex.

Basically, you shouldn't allow users to modify such an item (keep it hidden or *display only*).

- In Apex, we usually create a **process** which sets the primary key item's value, such as

  ```
  :P1_PK_ITEM := NVL(:P1_PK_ITEM, sequence_name.nextval);
  ```
- Or, set that item's **default value** to fetch sequence's next value.
- Or, create a **database trigger** which will populate column value *before insert*.
- Or, if your database version is high enough (12c and later), create an **identity column**.